# Updating WordPress

Tags: plugins, database

I have just update my WordPress page and I can't see it. A lot of plugins are giving errors, so I activate DEBUG. Then I have try to desactivate all plugins in the database. To make this I erase the option_value of active_plugins, but now I can only see a blank page when I enter my website, neither the errors!!

Answer (score 4):

## First

**Never modify the database options directly.**  Instead, to deactivate all of your plugins, FTP to your site and rename the `/plugins` directory as `/plugins-1` or something along those lines.  WordPress will automatically deactivate them the next time you try to load the site, then you can change the name back to `/plugins`.

## Troubleshooting

There are several steps your should take to debug an update:

### 1 - Deactivate Plugins

You seem to have done this already.  Good job.

### 2 - Activate the Default Theme

Some themes aren't compatible with newer versions of WordPress.  Switch your active theme from whatever it is now to TwentyEleven (the default that ships with WordPress 3.2.X).  If this fixes the problem, then the problem was your theme.

### 3 - Ask For Help

For the record, ***the WordPress Answers StackExchange is not a support forum.***

If you need specific help with your site, go to the [official support forums](http://wordpress.org/support) and ask.  Make sure you detail, step-by-step, exactly what you did, what error messages you saw, and what problems you're facing.

"A lot of plugins are giving errors" doesn't help us at all if we don't know what errors you're seeing.  Many times, these errors will tell us what went wrong so we can then help you fix the problem.

### LAST - Restore from Backups

You *did* back things up before you ran the upgrade, right?  This is exactly the reason WordPress lists this message on the update screen:

[image: WordPress Update Warning]

So restore your site back to it's pre-update state by re-installing the older version of WordPress and restoring your database from the backup file.

Answer (score 1):

Adding my 1 cent to @EAMann 's awesome answer... After updating WordPress, if you see a blank site or an error that says 'Site down for maintenance', use FileZilla or whatever FTP program you use, and delete the '.maintenance' file from your WP installation's root folder. You may need to set hidden files visible for doing this.